# How to programmatically create a <script> tag and a script inside an ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

From time to time I run into situation in which I could solve a given problem by dynamicly creating piece of JavaScript, spesific to that instance of the page, that I could then insert in the final markup. Usualy this is because I want some behaviour to happen on the client side, rather than on the server side and creating a static JavaScript isn't an option.
For example, when [trying to submit a files original path without submitting the file itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625524/how-to-submit-a-files-original-path-and-filename-without-submitting-the-file-its), when trying to do it for multiple dynamicly created components.

How would you recommend me to create a `script` tag and populate it with, for example, JavaScript?

Comment: Do you want your script tag inside the <head> block or anywhere in the <form runat=server> block?

Comment: Providing a simple example of "a given problem" would help?

Comment: @Philippe: I do belive anywhere inside the <form> tag would do fine. Of course, someone else might appriciate a solution for the <head> tag as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use your page's `ClientScriptManager` and it's [`RegisterClientScriptBlock()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx) method.

```
string javascript = "javascript goes here"; 
string scriptname = "Name of this script"; // used to prevent adding the same script twice at two places in the page life cycle
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(scriptname)) 
{ 
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page.GetType(), scriptname, javascript, true); 
}
```

Comment: Writing javascript in code-behind is a bad practice. When you need to tweak or change the behavior of UI, you need to recompile all the project.

Comment: Good point.  Even better if you can do this using RegisterClientScriptInclude

Comment: I misunderstood the original question. I voted up your answer. I'll check for RegisterClientScriptInclude when needed, thanks alot!

Comment: You could also create an HttpHandler (*.ashx) file to spit out the javascript, and just use a normal script tag in your markup that points to that handler.